# pyOpenSSL still on Mac even though I uninstalled it

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyopenssl

Running this gives me:

```
*******************************$ python -c 'import OpenSSL; print(OpenSSL.__version__)'

0.13.1
```

However,

```
*******************************$ pip uninstall pyopenssl
Cannot uninstall requirement pyopenssl, not installed
```

No idea what's wrong, please help.

Comment: Check `OpenSSL.__file__`, if the module is in a system directory, you can't remove it.

Comment: It's `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL/__init__.pyc` so what can I do I wanted to install version 0.14 not 0.13.1

Comment: You can probably use a virtual environment. Google virtualenv for more information.